# Android java draw the bitmap on canvas after changing orientation

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to draw a bitmap of the view/activity using Canvas api  after changing the orientation of the screen to landscape. But seems like I am missing something.Can any please suggest the solution for this?

```
//change the orientation of activity  
mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);  

// draw it on the canvas 
View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().draw(canvas);
```

I am even checking the whether or not the orientation is landscape or not and it does show me that the orientation has changed.

```
int o = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; //o=2
```

Comment: You could reuse `view` for drawing. How do you call these actions; in which methods? Are you sure `measure` and `layout` of `view` were called?

Comment: this is not a part of application development but rather a test library that I am trying to write and take the screenshots of view/activity once test fails .I was using spoon library to do that but that library doesn't give to desired results(i.e. doesn't take screen shots for landscape view ) so I am planning to ditch that library as it solves part of the problem. So far this is giving me a portrait bitmap of the activity even though it orientation is changed. What I am observing is that the `Width and Height` of the view is not will changing after orientation of activity.

Comment: That sounds interesting. But I'm still wondering if your code is part of one or two methods.

Comment: two different classes 1. testclass/testmethod which changes the orientation and 2. abstract class that draws the canvas as per the activity. here is the snapshot - [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/xKBIx7qtI)